# How to show the author of Blocked users's Content as anonymous in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I have a Content type Board. All authenticated users can add boards. when i displaying the Board's Nodes i am also showing the author name. All going good.
But when a user delete his account i set his status as blocked.
If a user has been blocked then i want to show Anonymous author on board's node created by that blocked user.
I searched here and there but could not find solution. Any Help please
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And finally, i solved it by following code:

```
    <?php $author= user_load($uid); ?>
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
<span class="submitted">

<!-- For blocked user set the user name as Anonymous -->
  <?php if(user_is_blocked($author->name)): ?>

    <span> <a href="#" title="" class="username" ><?php print t('Anonymous'); ?></a></span>

  <?php else: ?>

    <?php print($user_picture); ?>
    <?php print($submitted);?>

  <?php endif;?>
</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You may use

```
function theme_username($variables)
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_username/7.x

$username = $variables['name'];

Check if user blocked

```
$variables['name'] = 'anonymous';
```

Comment: I could not solve by this. but it helped me a lot to fix my problem. thanks